# DOM XML creating new element instead of appending

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm trying to create a simple applying process that would save the input of the user to an xml document since this is very temporary (and a learning thing). At first it was creating a new element for "applications" when I wanted it to append to that element so I commented it out and tried to get the elements tag.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['position'];
echo $_GET['name'];
echo $_GET['email'];
echo $_GET['minecraft-name'];
echo $_GET['age'];
echo $_GET['message'];


$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('dump.xml');
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "applications" );
//$r = $doc->createElement("applications");
//$doc->appendChild($r);

$s = $doc->createElement($_GET['position']);

$name = $doc->createElement("name");
$name->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode($_GET['name'])
);
$s->appendChild($name);

$email = $doc->createElement("email");
$email->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode($_GET['email'])
);
$s->appendChild($email);

$mcname = $doc->createElement("minecraft-name");
$mcname->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode($_GET['minecraft-name'])
);
$s->appendChild($mcname);

$age = $doc->createElement("age");
$age->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode($_GET['age'])
);
$s->appendChild($age);

$message = $doc->createElement("message");
$message->appendChild(
  $doc->createTextNode($_GET['message'])
);
$s->appendChild($message);

$r->appendChild($s);


echo $doc->save("dump.xml");
```

prints the error "Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::appendChild()".

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "applications" );
```

you want

```
$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "applications" )->item(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I forgot about the last part. There's no formating for any new created elements. 'formatOutput' is true as well

Comment: Someone else needs to help on formatting the output, I am not familiar with that part of the PHP DOM API.